# How to uninstall old Xcode beta safely

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to uninstall Xcode 5 beta 5 before installing beta 6 (I know it's under NDA, but as long as I don't mention anything about the software itself, I think we're good). What's the best/safest way of doing that, so I don't jeopardize any functionality? I'm just afraid of arbitrarily deleting things from the developer folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go into your developer folder and in the `About Xcode.pdf` it will have instructions

```
/Developer/Developer/About\ Xcode.pdf
```

It is near the end of the pdf but you can search for `uninstall` and it will give you some options

You will most likely want

```
sudo <Xcode>/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all
```

But I recommend you read the uninstall section so you can see the options available.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that's what I want. And then after I do that, I can just run the new installer and everything should work as expected?

Comment: Yup I I believe that's what I normally do. I'm sure I have read about it possibly required a restart but I can't seem to find that note now but if you run into any trouble it is worth a try.

Comment: Don't leave out the restart, I ran into problems until I did that step.

Comment: I can´t find the Developer folder. Where is it located? I´ve searched the my whole mac. Any advice?

Comment: This is a very very old question. Developer tools used to be installed under `/Developer` but now I believe you just delete Xcode app by dragging it to trash

Comment: @Paul.s i have xcode 6.1 and xcode 6.3 beta in my macbook. now i want uninstall xcode 6.3 beta but i am not able to do . i tried drag and drop in trash but its not working

Answer (score 35):

The above answer is correct for older versions of Xcode that install in the `/Developer/` folder, but newer versions of Xcode Beta can be uninstalled by simply dragging the `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app` application into the Trash.

Comment: But what if it doesn't let you because some of its extensions are in use?

Comment: @Alper make sure Xcode and Simulator are closed first

Comment: Make sure ALL copies of Xcode are closed first. In my case I had the GM version of Xcode running but the beta was not running. Once I quit the GM version I was able to delete the beta.

Comment: `The item “Xcode-beta” can’t be moved to the Trash because some of its extensions are in use.`

Answer (score 18):

You can do the following to fix (remove xcode/xcode beta).

> The item xcode can’t be moved to the Trash because some of its
>   extensions are in use.

1. Control-click on Xcode
2. Select `show package contents`
3. Open folder
4. Delete `plugins` folder
5. Open finder window
6. Navigate to folder containing Xcode app
7. Move to trash

Answer (score 16):

Just close non-beta Xcode first.

Comment: simple as that :)

Answer (score 6):

The answer is correct but just for older versions of Xcode. With newer versions:

1. Just trash the `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app` application

and, **if you're replacing it with a new stable version** (new Xcode.app), remember to:

2. run `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app` to specify the new app that you wish to use for command line developer tools.

If "*the app can’t be moved to the Trash because some of its extensions are in use*", just restart the Mac before trying again.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode-beta.app was in ~/Downloads for me, version 12.2 RC.