# upgrade to xcode 6 beta 2 version

Tags: ios8, xcode6

I'm quite new to iOS programming. The current version of Xcode I have now is (version 6.0 6A215I).
How can I update the current version of Xcode to the latest version (beta2)?

Comment: While this was put on hold, the answer is far from obvious. Unless you have some experience with beta versions, one would expect some other mechanism (such as through the App Store, or Xcode itself) rather than delete current beta and downloading the whole thing. Now, how is this Xcode-related off topic? Xcode questions (like Xcode is crashing, or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129258/how-to-uninstall-old-xcode-beta-safely) are legit right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the previous version and install the new one, or just copy the new version keeping the previous version. Anyway you should download the new version from apple dev website.